# Is it good to buy Canon 18-135mm lens?

Tags: canon, canon-70d

I have Canon EOS 70d DSLR and I have two lenses as Canon 50mm f 1.8 and Sigma 70-300mm. I work with these lenses and it good. Now, I like to add some more lenses like some zoom lens like  Canon 18-135mm as its is quite cheap and have seen good reviews on ebay and amazon sites. But I am confused now should I have to buy this lens or not? as I have two lenses which I have mentioned above, Does the needs of canon 18-135mm lens would be fulfill by that lenses or not? As one of the main features that I like to buy this lens is due to image stabilizer feature on it. So can anyone recommend me what should be the best options for buying lens.

Comment: This is something a subjective issue so I'll comment rather than answer. This seems a pointless purchase to me. What will you use it for that your current lenses don't cover? The image quality will probably be best in the middle of the zoom range, but it won't match up to your 50mm. And your 70-300 will probably give better IQ at 135mm than the 18-135mm. The only advantage you will have is that you won't need to swap lenses and you'll have the wider end to play with. So it depends what's more important, IQ or convenience. I know what I'd go for. Look at decent wide-angle zooms instead, I say.

Comment: Necessary? No. Why would it be necessary? - Whether it is advisable will depend on what you want to photograph how.

Comment: I think there is a language issue here. The word "necessary" is very strong, especially when you don't qualify it. Do you mean that you feel it is necessary to have a wider angle lens, and are wondering if this would be a good way to fill that? Or do you wonder if it's necessary to have a wide angle lens at all?

Comment: I want to upgrade some lenses so I am asking the questions so that I could come to the solution that should I buy the 18-135mm lenses or not. Let it be..

Comment: In general, "what should I buy" questions aren't a good fit for this Site as they are both rapidly outdated and specific to your individual circumstances. If you could try and rephrase your question to explain what problem you're trying to solve, it would be a much better question.

Comment: In that case, the answer is definitely **no you should not buy this lens now**. There is no necessity to have this lens in the abstract. You should wait until you have an actual need to fill, and then buy the thing that fits your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are missing with your current lenses.

The 18-135mm is a nice lens that can do a lot but it isn't very good at anything - it's relatively slow at f/3.5-f/5.6, 18mm is wide but not very wide, 135mm is long but not very long, the lens has ok but not great image quality, the auto-focus is ok (much better than the 50 f/1.8) but not great, the IS is ok but not the best, you get the point.

I have the 18-135 and I love it because it does almost everything I need on a daily basis - it covers everything I need to take photos at acceptable parent-child distance in acceptable quality and without swapping lenses.

if you want something that covers everything from sort-of-wide to sort-of-tele with ok quality then the 18-135 is for you. if you want anything more specific (or faster, or higher quality) there are better option out there.